# How to inject correct bean on runtime on Spring

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

My title may not be descriptive enough or misleading let me explain the real story.

I've 3 kafka consumers running on the same spring boot app listening different topics, all have their own threads. All of the 3 consumers work exactly the same; process the queue and send them to another rest service. The only difference is that they send the data to different rest services thus I explicitly select the correct `RestClient` to send the data as in the example

```
    @Autowired
    internal var restClients: Map<String,RestClient>? = null

    fun getOSStats(restClientName: String): Response {
        val restClient = restClients[restClientName]
        return restClient.performRequest(...)
    }
```

I have to pass the `clusterName: String` to all the methods starting from the consumer just to pick the correct `RestClient` which is defined by the consumer.

**What I want to achieve is**

```
    @Autowired
    internal var restClient:RestClient? = null

    fun getOSStats(): Response {
        return restClient.performRequest(...)
    }
```

What is the best way to inject the correct bean instead of explicitly select the bean from a map?

I use Spring 5.x and kotlin

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch between clients in runtime I believe that such lookup `map` is actually good solution

If you know string value and it's defined for every consumer just use the `Qualifier` Spring annotation to specify which implementation of the service interface should be autowired to your consumer

```
 @Bean("client1Client")
 // Bean creating method

 ...

 // and in the 1st consumer class
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("client1Client")
 internal var restClient:RestClient
```